# Implementing mysql intersection

Tags: mysql, sql, intersection

I'm trying to do a filter search functionality in codeigniter. I have a table named products and my system has the functionality to filter these products by category and by date. I have a mysql code in mind which looks something like this:

```
SELECT * from products WHERE product_category='Cloth'
INTERSECT
SELECT * from products WHERE ('insert date logic here')
```

So it should return records (via id) from the same table named products. However, there's no INTERSECT in mysql so I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my code just for the part of the product category

```
$this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from product_advertised WHERE quantity > 0 AND prodcatid='.$prodcats[0].' LIMIT '.$start.','.$limit);

    if(sizeof($prodcats > 1)) {
        $query_str = "SELECT * FROM product_advertised WHERE quantity>0 AND ";
        $str="";
        for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($prodcats);$i++) {
            if($i != sizeof($prodcats)-1) {
                $str = $str. "prodcatid=".$prodcats[$i]." OR ";
            }
            else {
                $str = $str. "prodcatid=".$prodcats[$i]." LIMIT ".$start.",".$limit;
            }
        }
        $query_str .= $str;
        $query = $this->db->query($query_str);
    }
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use `and`?

```
SELECT *
from products
WHERE product_category = 'Cloth' AND
      ('insert date logic here');
```

Comment: this is my code just for the part of product categories,, without the dates yet. and it's kinda complex already... so i dont know if doing just a simple and would do :/  (in the edit)